# Testing (test-unit) a meta tag's name and content to make sure the content is not empty

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing, attributes, assert

I'm having a really hard time figuring out how to make sure a meta title's content attribute is not empty using either assert_select or assert_tag. I can't figure out how to get it to work together.

To give you a better idea, here's an example of how I would like the test to work:

**This should pass:**

[meta name="title" content="Hello" /]

**This should fail:**

[meta name="title" content="" /]

[note: Having no tag at all should also fail]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I got it to work shortly after posting with a little help from IRC and the documentation example as a base. Rather than delete the post I'll keep it up because this was surprisingly annoying to track down.

Here's the code:

```
assert_select "meta[name=title]" do
  assert_select "[content=?]", /.+/
end
```

Comment: assert_select "meta[name=title][content=?]", /.+/ for shortcut :-)